# Android - Missing Font file from asset

Tags: android, fonts, runtimeexception

I have added my own fonts to a font directory and placed it in the assets directory. For some reason every now and then my project crashes when trying to retrieve one of the fonts.

i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found font/Helvetica-Bold.ttf
```

cleaning the project works. I have this same setup in other projects and it works fine. What could be the reason why it cant find the font and i have to clean the project.

i am using

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

Also note that i have had to add the asset directory as it wasn't there when i created the project

Comment: Must be a problem with build tools 24.0.0 and/or instant run, try disabling instant run

Comment: thanks i will try that and see if it happens again

Comment: @GregEnnis this looks to have been the problem, not sure if you want to write an answer for this. I expect Android will fix this up when they fully release 24